# How to write a RoundDown() function with loops, + - * / and % (modulo)?

Tags: rounding, modulo, floor

I was just thinking, if you only had loops, + - * / and % (modulo).
Would it be possible to round a float number down to the next integer?
For example 278.791 to 278?

I've been thinking about that for a long time now, but still couldn't find a solution. Is it even possible?

Comment: How are you expecting `%` to work for floats?  (It varies for different languages: some languages don't implement % for floats at all; others have different behaviours for negative operands.)  Oh, and what do you mean by "round down"?  Which way should -2.3 round, for example?

Comment: I don't know, I thought the behavior of % was standardized just like the behavior of +-* and / are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python % works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
x = 278.791
y = x - (x % 1)
print x, y
```

In C other methods must be used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    float x = 278.791;
    float y = fmod(x,1.0);
    printf("%f, %f\n", x, y);
    x = 278.791;
    y = x - (int)x;
    printf("%f, %f\n", x, y);
}
```

Comment: Nice. From my testing I can tell, in javascript and C# you can the the % method and for php you have to use fmod.